# Convert multi for loop if/else into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert this into a list comprehension.

**Current Code**

```
some_list = [[{"apple":"red"}, {"orange":"orange"}, {"pineapple":"yellow"}, [{"box":"brown"}, {"table":"grey"}, {"seat":"green"}], {"grapes":"purple"}, {"cherry":"red"}]]

category_list = []
for item in some_list:
    tag_list = []
    for elem in item:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            for x in elem:
                tag_list.append(x)
        else:
            tag_list.append(elem)
            
    category_list.append(tag_list)
    
category_list
```

**Desired Output**

```
[[{'apple': 'red'},
  {'orange': 'orange'},
  {'pineapple': 'yellow'},
  {'box': 'brown'},
  {'table': 'grey'},
  {'seat': 'green'},
  {'grapes': 'purple'},
  {'cherry': 'red'}]]
```

**My Attempt**

```
[[x for x in elem] if isinstance(elem, list) else elem for item in some_list for elem in item]
```

**Results**

```
[{'apple': 'red'},
 {'orange': 'orange'},
 {'pineapple': 'yellow'},
 [{'box': 'brown'}, {'table': 'grey'}, {'seat': 'green'}],
 {'grapes': 'purple'},
 {'cherry': 'red'}]
```

But this just gets me right back to where I started.

Comment: "But this just gets me right back to where I started"—how are your input and desired output different? They appear to be identical. **Edit:** Oh, I see. There's a third nested inner list in the input containing `"box"`, `"table"`, and `"seat"`. This is exactly the kind of thing that would be helpful to have called out explicitly in your question. Make it easy for us to help you. See [ask].

Comment: Two of the design goal of list comprehension are the reduction of complexity and the increase of readability. You seem to walk in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I just updated my results to show the difference.

Comment: @KlausD.Sorry my question wasn't "What is the design goal of list comprehensions?" Again, my sincerest apologies this wasn't clear when I wrote: "I'm trying to convert this into a list comprehension."

Comment: you want to remove the third '[' and the first ']'? no? so maybe what you want to do is not so clear?!

Comment: @wotter Thank you for your question. I basically need to unpack the third list and keep the order. If you look at the Desired vs Results you can see how all dictionaries are unpacked and retain the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this comprehension:

```
some_list = [[{"apple":"red"}, {"orange":"orange"}, {"pineapple":"yellow"}, [{"box":"brown"}, {"table":"grey"}, {"seat":"green"}], {"grapes":"purple"}, {"cherry":"red"}]]

categories = [x if type(x) == dict else y for x in some_list[0] for y in x]

print(categories)
# Prints 
# [{'apple': 'red'}, {'orange': 'orange'}, {'pineapple': 'yellow'}, 
# {'box': 'brown'}, {'table': 'grey'}, {'seat': 'green'}, 
# {'grapes': 'purple'}, {'cherry': 'red'}]
```

This appends the element if it's a dictionary, otherwise appends each element in the element (which would be a list).

Note: I'm actually new to list comprehension so let me know if I made any mistakes!